# complex SQL query tuning

Tags: sql, performance, vertica

Hello I have a query that's taking a lot of time to execute and consuming so much resources, the query is similar to this:

```
WITH first_match AS (
        SELECT t1.name
               , t1.lastname
               , t2.location
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
        table2 t2 
        ON t1.name = t2.name
)
, second_match AS (
        SELECT t1.name
                , t1.lastname
                , t2.location
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
        table2 t2
        ON t1.name = SUBSTR(t2.name,0,INSTR(t2.name,'-'))
        WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t2.name,'[-]')
        AND (t1.name, t1.lastname) NOT IN (SELECT name, lastname FROM first_match)
)
, third_match AS (
        SELECT t1.name
                ,t1.lastname
                ,t2.location
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
        table2 t2
        ON t1.name = REGEXP_REPLACE(t2.name, 'uselesssuffix', '')
        WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t1.name, 'uselesssuffix')
        AND (t1.name, t1.lastname) NOT IN (
                                SELECT name, lastname FROM first_match
                                UNION
                                SELECT name, lastname FROM second_match
                                )
)
, fourth_match AS (
        SELECT t1.name
                ,t1.lastname
                ,t2.location
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
        table2 t2
        ON t1.name = SUBSTR(t2.name, 0, 7)
        WHERE LENGTH(t2.name) > 6
        AND (t1.name, t1.lastname) NOT IN (
                                SELECT name, lastname FROM first_match
                                UNION
                                SELECT name, lastname FROM second_match
                                UNION
                                SELECT name, lastname FROM third_match
                                )
)
, final_result AS (
SELECT * FROM first_match
UNION
SELECT * FROM second_match
UNION
SELECT * FROM third_match
UNION
SELECT * FROM fourth_match
)
SELECT * FROM final_result;
```

Where I have two tables and trying to join between them on let's say 4 possible conditions, the first CTE contains the result of the first condition, the second contains the entries not included in the first and comply to the second condition, the third contains the remaining that also comply to the third condition etc..
thus the use of
`AND (t1.name, t1.lastname) NOT IN (SELECT name, lastname FROM first_match)..`
condition,
and eventually I use UNION to generate the final result, now the relatively big number of CTEs (5 in this case) and the big number of UNION, and conditions is turning this query to a heavy one and takes so much resources and so much time to execute,
any ideas on whether there's a better way to implement the same scenario but with a different approach, maybe in one CTE

Answer (score 1):

Am I getting something wrong here?

In a complex join involving several Boolean expressions OR-ed together, the evaluation stops with the first expression of those that evaluates to TRUE.

So why not this?

```
    SELECT   t1.name
           , t1.lastname
           , t2.location
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 
    ON t1.name = t2.name
    OR  (    -- REGEXP_LIKE(t2.name,'[-]')
             -- AND t1.name = SUBSTR(t2.name,1,INSTR(t2.name,'-')-1)
         t1.name=SPLIT_PART(t2.name,'-',1)
    )
    OR  (    -- REGEXP_LIKE(t1.name, 'uselesssuffix') 
             -- AND t1.name = REGEXP_REPLACE(t2.name, 'uselesssuffix', '')
         t1.name=SPLIT_PART(t2.name,'uselesssuffix',1)
    )
    OR  (    LENGTH(t2.name) > 6
         AND t1.name = SUBSTR(t2.name, 1, 7)
    )
```

.. and while I was at it, I tried to reduce the necessary function calls ...

And , in Vertica, SUBSTR() begins at the 1st , not at the 0th, position of a string.. :-]

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple matches that you are trying to prioritize.  One thing to try is a series of `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.lastname,
       COALESCE(t2_1.location, t2_2.location, , . . . )
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2_1 
     ON t1.name = t2_1.name LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2_2
     ON t1.name = SUBSTR(t2_2.name, 1, INSTR(t2_2.name, '-')) AND
        t2_2.name LIKE '%-%' AND
        t2_1.name IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2_3
     ON t1.name = REGEXP_REPLACE(t2_3.name, 'uselesssuffix', '') AND
        t1.name LIKE '%uselesssuffix%' AND
        t2_1.name IS NULL AND
        t2_2.name IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     . . .
WHERE t1.name IS NOT NULL OR
      t2_1.name IS NOT NULL OR
      . . .
```

Note that each new condition checks that all the previous conditions do not match.

Comment: `ON t1.name = SUBSTR(t2_2.name, 1, INSTR(t2_2.name, '-'))
        t2_2.name LIKE '%-%' AND
        t2_1.name IS NULL LEFT JOIN`
here we have `AND` before `t2_2.name LIKE '%-%'` right ?